# Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to update coordinate points by comparing them to image intensity values.
Part of that is being done by the following code:

```
mult_factor = int((len(gradients_fine) - 1) / (len(trace) - 1))
mult_scale = np.linspace(1, 0, mult_factor, endpoint=False)

gradients_coarse[:-1] += np.matmul(np.moveaxis(
    gradients_fine[:-1].reshape((-1, mult_factor, 2)) , 1, 2), mult_scale)
```

Here, the last line with np.matmul doesn't work. So gradients_coarse is just an empty np.zeros_like array, gradients_fine is a numpy array of type float64 and the variable "trace" is also a numpy array with shape (126, 2).
Why does this code yield the following error?

```
 gradients_fine[:-1].reshape((-1, mult_factor, 2)) , 1, 2), mult_scale)

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information about the variables to be sure, I suspect it's the `+=` that's giving the error.

I can generate the error message with

```
In [131]: x=np.arange(3)
In [132]: x
Out[132]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [133]: x += 1.23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-133-fc7abc6ba93f>", line 1, in <module>
    x += 1.23
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

This is trying to add a float value to an int dtype array.

Comment: Could you elaborate why one can not just add a float value to an int dtype array? It's Python after all, so I had expected that the int dtype array was just converted to a float dtype array.

Comment: @NerdOnTour, `x+1.23` does produce a float array.  But '+=' like operations cannot change the `dtype` of an array.  It's `numpy` that's controlling that, not the base python.